# Laravel broadcast event's constructor call's type hinted model relations again

Tags: php, laravel

I haven't been able to figure out for days now as to why the following behaviour, that I describe at the bottom, takes place.
The basic idea for the following code is to update a task, and

- broadcast `EmployeeTaskAttached` event to employees who have been assigned for the task
- broadcast `EmployeeTaskDetached` for those employees who have been removed from the task
- `TaskEmployeesChanged` for those employees that have not been affected but need to update their task employee lists with newly added/removed employees
- `Task` model should be broadcasted with relations loaded

## Task controller

Here I update some of the `Task` fields, get the id's of attached/detached employees from the `sync()` returned data and broadcast events accordingly.
Notice that I load task relations that are needed for the view, where the tasks are shown.
 `$task->load('project','status','parent_task','tags') ;`

```
 public function update (Request $request, Task $task)
{    
  $task->name = $request->task['name'];
  $task->date_due = $request->task['date_due'];
  $task->type()->associate($request->task['task_type_id']);  
  $task->status()->associate($request->task['status_id']);
  $task->load('project','status','parent_task','tags') ;

  if($request->has('task.employees') )
  {
    $originalEmployees = $task->employees->pluck('id'); 
    $changedEmployees = $task->employees()->sync($request->input('task.employees',[]));
    $detachedEmployees = $changedEmployees['detached'];
    $attachedEmployees = $changedEmployees['attached'];
    //$employeesToUpdate contains the original task employee id's that have not been detached or attached
    $employeesToUpdate = $originalEmployees->diff(array_merge($detachedEmployees,$attachedEmployees ));
    if( $attachedEmployees || $detachedEmployees)
    { 
      //broadcasted only if there is a change in employees
      broadcast(new TaskEmployeesChanged($task,$employeesToUpdate));
    }
    if($attachedEmployees)
    { 
      broadcast(new EmployeeTaskAttached($task,collect($attachedEmployees)));
    }
    if($detachedEmployees)
    {
     broadcast(new EmployeeTaskDetached($task,collect($detachedEmployees)));
    } 

  }  
  $task->save();
}
```

## Broadcast event

This is one of the events, but the same behaviour takes place for the other ones.

```
namespace App\Events\Tasks;  
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;  
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;  
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;  
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;  
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;  
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;  
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;  
use App\Models\Task;  
use App\Interfaces\UserInterface;  
class EmployeeTaskAttached implements ShouldBroadcast  
{  
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;  

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $task,$employee_id ;
    public function __construct(Task $task,$employee_id   )
    {
      $this->task = $task;
      $this->employee_id = $employee_id; 
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    { 
      $task_list_channels = $this->employee_id->map(function ($id){
        $channel = new PrivateChannel('task_list_'.$id);
       return $channel;
      }) 
      ->all();

      return $task_list_channels; 
    } 


}
```

## Problem

The event itself is broadcasted and recieved succesfully, the one thing that i dont get is why the `Task` model relations, that are loaded already in the controller, are loaded again in the event, therefore, duplicating the database queries.
When I open up the Laravel Telescope tool, I can see that the neccesary queries are executed in the controller but once the `Task` model is passed to the event, the event job runs some of the queries, that have been executed in the controller,  again. In the end, if I remove and add some employees from the task, up to ~40 queries have been run, even though it should take around 17 queries.
If I log the `Task` model, that is passed to the event, in constructor before this line `$this->task = $task;`, I can see that the relationships are already loaded, but when `$this->task = $task;` is executed, laravel loads the relationships again.
Shouldnt the relationships be already loaded?If not, how could I reduce the amount of queries?
Might this be a Laravel Telescope glitch and those queries are no actually executed?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the `SerializesModels` trait. Your Task model would be serialized and put on the queue. Maybe the relationships are then reloaded when it gets pulled off the queue for the broadcast.

Comment: @DelenaMalan You're right, this blog post explains it quite well https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/e60d6a932db98985f160146b09455988, it makes sense why it's designed that way. Thanks, you could post your comment as an answer maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel serializes the `Task` model instance when it is pushed to the queue. When the broadcast happens, the `Task` is re-retrieved from the database again.